# Deepin Linux: Onboard HDMI not working (shows only on boot/shutdown)

Tags: linux, display, hdmi

I have a Dell XPS desktop with Deepin Linux where the onboard HDMI doesn't work (no signal). 
Based on the Ubuntu collected from Ubuntu, Deeping is not identifying some HDMI ports (uname/xrandr/lshw from both systems below)
[Deepin]

```
$> uname -a
Linux deepin 4.15.0-29deepin-generic #31 SMP Fri Jul 27
07:12:08 UTC 2018 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$> sudo lshw -C video
[sudo] password for emerson: 
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208 [GeForce GT 730]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:141 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)


$> xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
VGA-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
      _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
      CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
      EDID: 
            00ffffffffffff000472e10349ea9052
            1d19010368301b78ca4fa3a655549e25
            0d5053bfef80714f8140818081c08100
            9500b300d1c0023a801871382d40582c
            4500dd0c1100001e000000fd00384c1f
            5311000a202020202020000000fc004b
            32323248514c0a2020202020000000ff
            005430454141303036383538310a00a4
      BorderDimensions: 4 
            supported: 4
      Border: 0 0 0 0 
            range: (0, 65535)
      SignalFormat: VGA 
            supported: VGA
      ConnectorType: VGA 
      ConnectorNumber: 2 
      _ConnectorLocation: 2 
      non-desktop: 0 
            supported: 0, 1
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    72.19    60.32    56.25  
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  

HDMI-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
      CscMatrix: 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 0 0 0 65536 0 
      BorderDimensions: 4 
            supported: 4
      Border: 0 0 0 0 
            range: (0, 65535)
      SignalFormat: TMDS 
            supported: TMDS
      ConnectorType: HDMI 
      ConnectorNumber: 1 
      _ConnectorLocation: 1 
      non-desktop: 0 
            supported: 0, 1

$> lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
deepin                      
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Skylake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Skylake PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:de000000-df0fffff ioport:d0000000(size=167772160)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GK208 [GeForce GT 730]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
                resources: irq:141 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display
             description: Display controller
             product: HD Graphics 530
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:132 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

[Ubuntu]
$ uname -a
Linux ubuntu 4.18.0-10-generic #11-Ubuntu SMP Thu Oct 11 15:13:55 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ sudo lshw -C video
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GK208B [GeForce GT 730]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:132 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)

$ xrandr --prop
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-D-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 54 
        supported: 54
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    dithering depth: auto 
        supported: auto, 6 bpc, 8 bpc
    dithering mode: auto 
        supported: auto, off, static 2x2, dynamic 2x2, temporal
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    underscan vborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan hborder: 0 
        range: (0, 128)
    underscan: off 
        supported: auto, off, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 56 
        supported: 56
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
VGA-1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000472e10349ea9052
        1d19010368301b78ca4fa3a655549e25
        0d5053bfef80714f8140818081c08100
        9500b300d1c0023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e000000fd00384c1f
        5311000a202020202020000000fc004b
        32323248514c0a2020202020000000ff
        005430454141303036383538310a00a4
    scaling mode: None 
        supported: None, Full, Center, Full aspect
    color vibrance: 150 
        range: (0, 200)
    vibrant hue: 90 
        range: (0, 180)
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 58 
        supported: 58
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.96    59.93  
   [We have more resolution options not included here]

DP-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 71 
        supported: 71
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-1-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 78 
        supported: 78
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
HDMI-1-2 connected primary 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
    _MUTTER_PRESENTATION_OUTPUT: 0 
    EDID: 
        00ffffffffffff000472e103d24e9070
        091b010380301b78ca39b0a554509e26
        115054bfef80714f8140818081c08100
        9500b300d1c0023a801871382d40582c
        4500dd0c1100001e000000fd00374c1f
        5311000a202020202020000000fc004b
        32323248514c0a2020202020000000ff
        005430454141303036383538360a0197
        020318b14f0102030405060790111213
        1415161f63030c00023a801871382d40
        582c4500dd0c1100001e011d8018711c
        1620582c2500dd0c1100009e011d0072
        51d01e206e285500dd0c1100001e8c0a
        d08a20e02d10103e9600dd0c11000018
        00000000000000000000000000000000
        00000000000000000000000000000097
    PRIME Synchronization: 1 
        supported: 0, 1
    Content Protection: Undesired 
        supported: Undesired, Desired, Enabled
    aspect ratio: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, 4:3, 16:9
    Broadcast RGB: Automatic 
        supported: Automatic, Full, Limited 16:235
    audio: auto 
        supported: force-dvi, off, auto, on
    link-status: Good 
        supported: Good, Bad
    CONNECTOR_ID: 82 
        supported: 82
    non-desktop: 0 
        range: (0, 1)
   1920x1080     60.00*+  60.00    50.00    59.94  
   [We have more resolution options not included here]

$ lshw
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
ubuntu                      
    description: Computer
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smp vsyscall32
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       physical id: 0
     *-pci
          description: Host bridge
          product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers
          vendor: Intel Corporation
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 07
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=skl_uncore
          resources: irq:0
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor PCIe Controller (x16)
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 07
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:16 ioport:e000(size=4096) memory:de000000-df0fffff ioport:d0000000(size=167772160)
           *-display
                description: VGA compatible controller
                product: GK208B [GeForce GT 730]
                vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: a1
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
                configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
                resources: irq:133 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:d0000000-d7ffffff memory:d8000000-d9ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
        *-display
             description: Display controller
             product: HD Graphics 530
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
             version: 06
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
             resources: irq:132 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: 100 Series/C230 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.0
             version: f1
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:17 memory:df300000-df3fffff
```

I have tried many different approachs that did not work,  and need to fix this.

Comment: Post updated. I can see from Ubuntu information that Deepin did not identify all HDMI ports.

Answer (score 0):

Since you made a

1. [Deepin ver 15.8 LiveUSB](https://cdimage.deepin.com/live-system/deepin-live-system-2.0-amd64.iso)
2. after [confirming its MD5 checksum](https://cdimage.deepin.com/live-system/MD5SUMS) showed an uncorrupted download
3. and there was no HDMI video boot from the Deepin LiveUSB
   but
4. an [Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS Live USB](https://releases.ubuntu.com/18.04.1/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso) made after
5. [verifying its checksum](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu) shows the ISO download was OK,
6. and you got HDMI video w/ Ubuntu successfully,

it's a flaw in the Deepin distribution not found in Ubuntu, which is also a Debian-derived distro. Therefore, I suggest you contact [Deepin Support](https://bbs.deepin.org/forum.php?mod=forumdisplay&fid=70).

Note: An alternative process to make a Debian LiveUSB is [available, but more complex](http://www.fabbnet.net/Live_Persistent.htm).